# Use of the function IsWin2000() produces a C++ warning: C4996 - Deprecated Function

Tags: c++, winapi, warnings, deprecated, suppress-warnings

So when I am using the function, IsWin2000(), to figure out whether or not the computer running my application is running windows 2000, i get the warning:

```
warning C4996: 'IsWin2000': This function is exported to support existing modules and is obsolete.
```

If this is an obsolete, deprecated function, what is the proper way to query what operating system is running? Is there any other way to achieve this task, or is my only option to simply suppress the warning? Thanks!

Comment: You shouldn't be doing this at all.  Why are you calling the function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`GetVersionEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724451%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

See the Remarks at [`OSVERSIONINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724834%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for a list of results and how to interpret them. See [Getting the System Version](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724429%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for a fully fledged example.

And lets not forget what the spec says:

> Identifying the current operating
>   system is usually not the best way to
>   determine whether a particular
>   operating system feature is present.
>   This is because the operating system
>   may have had new features added in a
>   redistributable DLL. Rather than using
>   GetVersionEx to determine the
>   operating system platform or version
>   number, test for the presence of the
>   feature itself

Answer (score 2):

This is not a standard Windows API function.  Maybe if you mention where you got it, we can provide more information.

The proper way depends on what you are trying to accomplish.  Creating a debug log or error report, you should call [`GetVersionEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724451.aspx).

For any other purpose, you should test for the actual feature you're trying to use, often with `GetProcAddress`, and not hard-code a version test.